# Fuzzy logic controller - RuntimeError: Unable to resolve rule execution order

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy, skfuzzy

I am new to this concept and i have been trying to implement an fuzzy logic controller for shower. the input are the postion of knob from extreme left to extreme right and outputs are tempreture from very cold to very hot. i am encountering this Runtime error  in the rules. Below is my stupid code

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

pos = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 180, 1), 'pos')
temp = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 100, 1), 'temp')

pos['EL'] = fuzz.trimf(pos.universe, [0, 0, 45])
pos['L'] = fuzz.trimf(pos.universe, [0, 45, 90])
pos['C'] = fuzz.trimf(pos.universe, [45, 90, 135])
pos['R'] = fuzz.trimf(pos.universe, [90, 135, 180])
pos['ER'] = fuzz.trimf(pos.universe, [135, 180, 180])

temp['VC'] = fuzz.trimf(temp.universe, [0, 0, 10])
temp['C'] = fuzz.trimf(temp.universe, [0, 10, 40])
temp['W'] = fuzz.trimf(temp.universe, [10, 40, 80])
temp['H'] = fuzz.trimf(temp.universe, [40, 80, 100])
temp['VH'] = fuzz.trimf(temp.universe, [80, 100, 100])

rule1 = ctrl.Rule(pos['EL'], temp['VC'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(pos['L'], temp['C'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(pos['C'], temp['W'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(pos['R'], temp['H'])
rule5 = ctrl.Rule(pos['ER'], temp['VH'])

temp_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5])
temprature = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(temp_ctrl)

RuntimeError: Unable to resolve rule execution order. The most likely reason is two or more rules that depend on each other. Please check the rule graph for loops.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want this

```
pos = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 180, 1), 'pos')
```

to be this

```
pos = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 180, 1), 'pos')
```

so your rules will read something like

```
if antecedent then consequent
```